# *Wait for app to launch* debug option in MonoTouch

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Is there a debug option like this in MonoTouch?

[image: description]

Comment: What do you need this for?  Just debug the app, then reopen the app if you are trying to test notifications or `HandleOpenUrl`.

Comment: Yes I'm testing `HandleOpenUrl`, and no I don't see a way to test it without this option. I'm resorting to Debug.WriteLine debugging now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start debugging on the device, then hit the home button.  The debugger should remain attached for `HandleOpenUrl`, when the app is relaunched.

Comment: Thank you this works. I was debugging an app which had "Application does not run in background" set to YES, so you method did not work. Changed it to NO for debugging `HandleOpenUrl`.

Comment: This won't help if you are trying to debug `HandleOpenUrl` from a cold start, since `FinishedLaunching` will not be called again hence the application is already running.

Comment: Yeah, `HandleOpenUrl` isn't actually called on a cold start, `FinishedLaunching` will contain the information in the options `NSDictionary`. Either case, there isn't an easy way to debug this.